# In Ruby/Rails, how to decrypt a string encrypted and signed by PKCS7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, encryption, pkcs#7

In [this RailsCast on PayPal](http://railscasts.com/episodes/143-paypal-security) it shows you how to encrypt a URL parameter before sending it to PayPal.

```
PAYPAL_CERT_PEM = File.read("#{Rails.root}/certs/paypal_cert.pem")
APP_CERT_PEM = File.read("#{Rails.root}/certs/app_cert.pem")
APP_KEY_PEM = File.read("#{Rails.root}/certs/app_key.pem")
def encrypt_for_paypal(values)
    signed = OpenSSL::PKCS7::sign(OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(APP_CERT_PEM),        OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(APP_KEY_PEM, ''), values.map { |k, v| "#{k}=#{v}" }.join("\n"), [], OpenSSL::PKCS7::BINARY)
    OpenSSL::PKCS7::encrypt([OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(PAYPAL_CERT_PEM)], signed.to_der, OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher::new("DES3"),        OpenSSL::PKCS7::BINARY).to_s.gsub("\n", "")
end
```

Suppose I was writing the code for PayPal's server. How would I decrypt this string? It appears to me that this code both public-key signs the string (to verify authenticity) and then encrypts the string (to provide privacy). What would the code be for doing the reverse, decrypting and verifying authenticity?

Thanks.

Comment: Already seen? http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/176646 and http://www.example-code.com/ruby/mime_pkcs7_decrypt.asp

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/176646 is talking about getting a detached signature. He seems to want to avoid getting "a pkcs7 file which is containing the payload of my testfile." I know how to get that file- it is what the RailsCasts code demonstrates. I need to know how to decrypt the payload once I have it.

The second link deals with a different encryption scheme, one that does not involve public/private keypairs, so it is not the correct solution to this question.

Answer (score 3):

Hi John here is an example of encryption / decryption using ruby openssl.
Note its using AES for the cypher as DES3 seemed to be dropped in my version of ruby openssl.
Calling gsub on the string to replace newlines seemed to break it so i have left it commented out.
Hope it helps you out.

```
require 'openssl'

PAYPAL_CERT_PEM = File.read("paypal_cert.pem")
@paypal_cert = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(PAYPAL_CERT_PEM)

APP_CERT_PEM = File.read("app_cert.pem")
@app_cert = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(APP_CERT_PEM)

APP_KEY_PEM = File.read("app_key.pem")
@app_key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(APP_KEY_PEM, '')

PAYPAL_KEY_PEM = File.read("paypal_key.pem")
@paypal_key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(PAYPAL_KEY_PEM, '')

CERT_STORE = OpenSSL::X509::Store.new
CERT_STORE.add_cert(@app_cert)

data = Hash.new
data['customer_id'] = '123456789'
data['customer_name'] = 'Mr Smith'

def encrypt_for_paypal(values)
data_name_values = values.map { |k, v| "#{k}=#{v}" }

signed_data = OpenSSL::PKCS7::sign(@app_cert, @app_key, data_name_values.join("\n"), [], OpenSSL::PKCS7::BINARY)

cypher = OpenSSL::Cipher::new("AES-128-CFB")

encrypted_data = OpenSSL::PKCS7::encrypt([@paypal_cert], signed_data.to_der, cypher, OpenSSL::PKCS7::BINARY)

encrypted_data.to_s #.gsub("\n", "")
end

def decrypt_by_paypal(encrypted_data)
received_encrypted_data = OpenSSL::PKCS7.new(encrypted_data)

received_signed_data = received_encrypted_data.decrypt(@paypal_key, @paypal_cert)

p7_received_signed_data = OpenSSL::PKCS7.new(received_signed_data)

p7_received_signed_data.verify(nil, CERT_STORE, nil, OpenSSL::PKCS7::NOVERIFY)

p7_received_signed_data.data
end

encrypted_txt = encrypt_for_paypal data
puts decrypt_by_paypal encrypted_txt
```

Comment: Using OpenSSL::PKCS7::NOVERIFY does not seem to care if the correct public key is even in the key store I would switch this to nil and use the default.